# Finding specific types of manuscripts of a journal

Tags: publications, literature-search, bioinformatics

I am considering writing an article to a journal. This journal ([Bioinformatics](https://academic.oup.com/bioinformatics)) accepts different manuscripts:

- Original Papers
- Discovery Notes
- Application Notes
- Reviews
- Letters to the Editor
- Conference Papers

In a different topics:

- Genome analysis
- Sequence analysis
- Phylogenetics
- Structural Bioinformatics
- Gene Expression
- Genetics and Population Analysis
- Systems Biology
- Data and Text Mining
- Databases and Ontologies
- Bioimage Informatics

In order to improve my article I would like to read similar papers of the same topic and type of manuscript. How can I search for Application Notes of System Biology?

If filtering by topic is not possible, at least filtering by type of manuscript would be desirable.

I can't ask my advisor for guidance, because he doesn't know the field. I tried using Google Scholar, but it doesn't retrieve the type of manuscript or the scope of each manuscript when I use the quotes. The advanced search of that journal doesn't include the options to filter by manuscript and scope. Pubmed doesn't list the types of manuscripts of this journal.

Comment: It's surprising that Google Scholar didn't meet your needs - perhaps the weak point is in topic searching, e.g. if the topics aren't listed in the article text. If you just want a few examples then a manual search may be the best option.

Comment: Usually in the pdf version of the paper the typpe of manuscript is printed unless it is an original paper. Yes I am considering removing the topic criterion or do manual research in some issues of the journal. But maybe there is a quicker method I could use... I will propose to Google Scholar to add this option but I am not confident of any response

Comment: What exactly is the journal name and website? If you want a specific answer, please give specific details.

Comment: @Tripartio See the edit. But I rather prefer to have a generic answer, than a specific answer for this journal, I (or others) might want to do the same for other journals

Answer (score 1):

First, try the Advanced Search interface of the specific journal or publisher. In this  case:

- Open https://academic.oup.com/bioinformatics/advanced-search.
- Under "Find a specific article", select Bioinformatics and press the Search button (the one in the first row).
- One the left, under "Article type", select the desired type, e.g., "Brief report".
- Again on the left, under "Section", select the desired section, e.g. "Systems biology".

Now only articles of type Brief report, in the section Systems biology are displayed.

If such a search interface is not available or gives irrelevant results, there are more general approaches:

- In [Scopus Advanced Search](https://www.scopus.com), use queries in the form:

  > EXACTSRCTITLE(Journal Name) AND DOCTYPE(document_type)

  You can find the list of possible document types in the [help](https://service.elsevier.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/11236/supporthub/scopus/) (field code DOCTYPE).
- In [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com), try queries in the form (include the quotes):

  > source:"Journal name" "Article type"